# Why is openstack Keystone not listening on port 5000

Tags: openstack, keystone

I have install keystone following this [link](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/pike/install/keystone-verify-ubuntu.html) . The installation process was okay until I got the point where I need to ask for token. The admin token request was okay but I could not get a token for the non-admin user (demo user). I check network ports and it seems keystone is not listening on port 5000. Previously, keystone is not listening on any port and I have to change the port number in /etc/apache2/sites-available/keystone.conf to 35357. After the change and restarting apache2, I was able to get the token for admin but could not get the token for the non admin user. I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

Can anyone help solve this problem.

```
ubuntu@controller:~$ sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23399/epmd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3328/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1824/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23541/beam.smp      
tcp        0      0 192.168.9.111:3306      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22608/mysqld        
tcp        0      0 192.168.9.111:11211     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24834/memcached     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11240/apache2       
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      23399/epmd          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1824/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::35357                :::*                    LISTEN      11240/apache2       
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      23541/beam.smp
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the stein version.

Did you change the 5000 port to 35357 port in keystone.conf setting?

For me, both 5000 and 35357 port settings were required.

My settings were as below.

```
Listen 5000
Listen 35357

<VirtualHost *:5000>
    WSGIDaemonProcess keystone-public processes=5 threads=1 user=keystone group=keystone display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup keystone-public
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      ErrorLogFormat "%{cu}t %M"
    </IfVersion>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/keystone.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/keystone_access.log combined

    <Directory /usr/bin>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:35357>
    WSGIDaemonProcess keystone-admin processes=5 threads=1 user=keystone group=keystone display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup keystone-admin
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-admin
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      ErrorLogFormat "%{cu}t %M"
    </IfVersion>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/keystone.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/keystone_access.log combined

    <Directory /usr/bin>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Change the Apache settings and try restarting.

Please check again when port number 5000 and 35357 port are up.

Thank you.